# Expected argument of type "string", "object" given at property path

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm trying to change a password of a user. The user is selected in a dropdownlist.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('password', PasswordType::class, array('label' => 'Password'))
        ->add('reset', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Reset'))
        ->add('username', EntityType::class, array('class' => User::class,
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
            },'choice_label'=>'username', 'label'=>'User'));

}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => User::class));
}
```

When the form is first rendered, i see the list of users. Then i fill in the new password en submit.
And then i get the error:
"Expected argument of type "string", "object" given at property path username". The error occures in the controller in line

> $form->handleRequest($request);

This is the controller:

```
    $form = $this->createForm(ResetPwdType::class, new User());

    $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $u = $form->get('username')->getData();
            $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $u->getUsername()]);

            $newPwd = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $form->get('password')->getData());
            $user->setPassword($newPwd);

            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($user);
            $entityManager->flush();
            $this->addFlash('success', 'Password reset!');
            $params = null;
            return $this->redirectToRoute('reset_pwd');


        }


    return $this->render(
        'security/resetpwd.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView()));
```

I'm think there is a property that needs to be a string in stead of an object. And that is just has got someting to do with the username property.
I've tried to add a toString methode on the User Entity without success.
What must i change to get ride of the error and save the new password to the db.

Comment: Are you sure the field `username` is supposed to be an EntityType or the RestPwdType is supposed to have `data_class` set as `User`? One of those seems to be the issue. Right now, when submitting the data, the form will try to do something like: `$user->setUsername(User $user)`, which probably does not make much sense. You could try a DataTransformer, but that seems to be overkill. Maybe remove the `data_class`, rename the `username` field to `user`, and then instead retrieve the user directly from the form use `$user = $form->getData('user')`.

Comment: @dbrumann I set data_class => null and didn't pass an object new User() to the form.  And guess ->  It works! Thank u for ur time!